# Handling switch statements in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, switch-statement

I have a react component that utilizes a switch statement and I want to provide a conditional render if and only if the default statement is not returned. Please see the below code for an example:

```
import React from 'react';

const SwitchStatement = ({condition}) => {
  switch (condition) {
    case "a":
      return (<div>hello</div>);
    case "b":
      return (<div>world</div>);
    case "c":
      return (<div>goodbye</div>);
    default:
      return null;
  }
};

const renderSwitchStatement = (condition) => (
  <SwitchStatement condition={condition} />
);

const renderComponent = ({condition}) => {
  const rendered = renderSwitchStatement(condition);
  if (rendered !== null) {
    return rendered;
  }
}
```

e.g. I am trying to write a function such that `SwitchStatement("d")` returns null, as declared from the default statement. Of course, this does not happen, as null is not returned but rather a react component instead. I can maybe accomplish this with if / else statements, but how do can I find out if a passing condition in a switch statement gets handled by the switch's default? Thanks.

Comment: Why not just return `SwitchStatement(condition)` directly?

Comment: I plan on using this as a dedicated component for a larger application and think it would be easier to provide it as a react component rather than a function.

Comment: And why can't you just `<SwitchStatement condition='...' />`?

Comment: I don't know exactly what the issue is here. If you return `<SwitchStatement condition="d" />` it should return null.

Comment: `renderSwitchStatement` is always going to return a component. You can cut this function out and say: `const rendered = SwitchStatement('d');` which would return `null`. This will always return a component unless you hit the default case.

Comment: thanks @NorianNyx, is there any way I can return the component but still detect when the default case is rendered e.g. when a component is rendered with null returned?

Comment: You could use a prop, I guess. Return a component from `SwitchStatement`'s default case with a prop of `isNull` or something similar and check it. Although, I would ask why you needed to do this since you will know that `null` was returned inside of an `else` statement in `renderComponent`.

Comment: @Jimmy Why would you want to do that? It seems like you're conflating concerns here.